# Question mark in structured content description

Tags: java, jsp, opencms

In opencms-modules.xml ,
I set the `<explorertype name="aboutus" key="fileicon.aboutus"`

and set the `fileicon.aboutus = About Us` in workplace.properties file

But when I create the new structured content in workspace, the item is showing as

```
??? fileicon.aboutus ???
```

Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have published the workplace.properties and restarted Tomcat afterwards as well.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I manually put the `workplace.properties` in `<Tomcat WEB-APP folder>/opencms/WEB-INF/com/mypackage` .